# select distinct + group by returning more than one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I expect the following query

```
SELECT distinct t.customer_code, t.amount_spent
from table t
where t.customer_code = 'ABF7EG'
group by t.customer_code, t.amount_spent
```

in PostgreSQL to return only one row, for instance: `ABF7EG 1000`
but this is the result:

```
customer_code   amount_spent
ABF7EG              934
ABF7EG             1362
ABF7EG             1820
ABF7EG             1939
ABF7EG             1953
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Spammed databases removed, please add back the ONE you are actually using

Comment: What do you want the one row to look like?

Comment: `distinct` **and** `group by` together hardly makes any sense to begin with

Comment: How would you calculate `ABF7EG 1000`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you need to do :

```
SELECT distinct on(t.customer_code), t.amount_spent
from table t
where t.customer_code = 'ABF7EG'
group by t.customer_code, t.amount_spent
```

but this is weird thing to  do in this case, please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes it is not a function ,in PostgreSQL you can have a distinct on specific column(s) rather all the columns by using `distinct on`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would expect that.  You have two keys in the `GROUP BY`, so each row in the result set has unique values for them.

I assume you want:

```
select t.customer_code, sum(t.amount_spent)
from table t
where t.customer_code = 'ABF7EG'
group by t.customer_code;
```

Or perhaps:

```
select t.customer_code, array_agg(distinct t.amount_spent)
from table t
where t.customer_code = 'ABF7EG'
group by t.customer_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to calculate with your `GROUP BY`. The following exampe performs a `sum()` and a `avg()`, but you need to chose for the [`aggretate function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html) that best suits your use case - not clear in your question.

```
CREATE TABLE t (customer_code TEXT, amount_spent INT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ABF7EG',934),
                     ('ABF7EG',1362),
                     ('ABF7EG',1820),
                     ('ABF7EG',1939),
                     ('ABF7EG',1953);

SELECT customer_code, sum(amount_spent), avg(amount_spent)
FROM t WHERE t.customer_code = 'ABF7EG'
GROUP BY customer_code;

 customer_code | sum  |          avg          
---------------+------+-----------------------
 ABF7EG        | 8008 | 1601.6000000000000000
```

Check this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9ed004421f0146ef9ace99d394b5ef6a).